# Collection Efficiency of Photon

Tags: experimental-technique, data-analysis

I am currently reading this paper:
http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.112.116802#references

In the second column of text in page 2, the author makes various claims about the number of photons detected and the collection efficiencies of different optical components.

> 'we detect 2.6 million counts per second from the QD with excitation
>   laser power above QD saturation. The trion lifetime is 0.65 ns; i.e.
>   the QD emits ∼7.7 × 10$^8$ photons per second when driven well above
>   saturation. Taking into account the effect of the ∼90 ns dead time of
>   our time-correlated single photon counting module, our overall
>   collection efficiency is 0.45%. After correcting for the SSPD
>   efficiency (≃40%), beam splitter (80%), and polarizer (50%) losses as
>   well as the fiber coupling efficiency (40%), we conclude that 7.0% of
>   the photons emitted by the QD are collected by the objective.'

QD - Quantum dot 
SSPD - Superconducting single-photon detector
TCSPC - time-correlated single photon counting

While I understand that the dead time of 90ns means that for every photon detected, the instrument will not be able to detect any photons for the next 90ns, I do not understand how it factors into the calculation to arrive at the $0.45\%$ overall collection efficiency.

The following is the steps that I did to try to arrive at the 0.45% collection efficiency:

Given the trion lifetime, $\tau$ $= 0.65ns$

no. of photons from radiative recombination per second $= 1s/0.65ns$ $= 1.538*10^9 $

no. of photons emitted by the sample $= 1.538*10^9 * 0.5 = 7.7*10^8$ (value given in the paper) 
 The factor of half is due to the fact that there is a thin metal gate with a power reflectance $R < 0.5$ deposited on the top surface (page 1, second column).

From the different collection efficiencies of the optical components, the resultant efficiency is straightforward:

$0.4*0.8*0.5*0.4 = 0.07$ i.e. $7\%$ (value given in the text)

Therefore, of the emitted photons 

 $7.7*10^8*0.07 = 5.36*10^7$ photons get detected by the SSPD (not the TCSPC module).

With these values I seem to be getting a much higher overall collection efficiency.

Can anyone clarify the steps taken to arrive at the overall collection efficiency of $0.45\%$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think "collected by the objective" is the number of photons which reach the detector, so 2.6E6 recorded events/second, with Poission arrival statistics, leads to their estimate of the number of incident photons (same as "collected").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.6 million counts, with each count producing a dead time of 90 nsec, gives a total dead time of .234 seconds / second. So the total number of counts should be 3.4 million counts (2.6 / (1 - .234), assuming no dead time. Since each QD emits 770 million photons per second, the detector efficiency is 3.4 / 770 (which I get as .44%).